# Java JNA use C file

Tags: java, c

I want to use a C code in Java and i heard that this is done using jna. I am following this tutorial : http://m-hewedy.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/java-native-access-jna-by-example.html

my C code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int helloFromC() {
    printf("Hello from C!\n");
    return 1;
}
```

In change my working directory to where my main.c was located and then

```
gcc -c main.c
gcc -shared -o main.dll main.o
```

This has created my main.dll file.
Next i wrote the java code and added the jna jar to the build path :

my Java code :

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
public class HelloWorld {


    public interface Add extends Library
    {
        Add INSTANCE = (Add) Native.loadLibrary("main", Add.class);
        int helloFromC();
    }
    static public void main(String argv[]) {
          Add lib = Add.INSTANCE;
          System.out.println(lib.helloFromC());
    }
}
```

And this is the error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'main': Native library (win32-x86-64/main.dll) not found in resource path ([file:/D:/eclipse/workspace/RXTX/bin/, file:/D:/eclipse/workspace/RXTX/lib/RXTXcomm.jar, file:/C:/Users/Angelo/Downloads/jna-4.1.0.jar])
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:271)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:398)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:147)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:412)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:391)
    at HelloWorld$Add.<clinit>(HelloWorld.java:8)
    at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:12)
```

The problem is that i do not know where do i have to place the dll. I think that may be the problem.

After putting my main.dll in `D:/eclipse/workspace/RXTX/bin/` it gives me this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

    at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native.java:1759)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:260)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:398)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:147)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:412)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:391)
    at HelloWorld$Add.<clinit>(HelloWorld.java:8)
    at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:12)
```

Comment: Did you try to put your `main.dll` file in one of the folders mentionned in the first line of your error (typically `D:/eclipse/workspace/RXTX/bin/` seems to be a good candidate) ?

Comment: I tried that and it gives me another error. Check my edit